# What is the most optimal and creative way to create a random Matrix with mostly zeros and some ones in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to create a random `Matrix` with values of zeros and ones. With this presumption, there will be more zeros instead of ones! So I guess there should be something like a weighted Bernoulli distribution to choose between 0 or 1 each time (and more probability for choosing 0). I prefer not to limit it to just nxn matrices! I can try in an utterly not standard way like this:

```
julia> let mat = Matrix{Int64}(undef, 3, 5)
           zero_or_one(shift) = rand()+shift>0.5 ? 0 : 1
           foreach(x->mat[x]=zero_or_one(0.3), eachindex(mat))
       end

julia> mat
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1  0  1
 0  1  1  1  1
 0  1  1  0  1
```

Note that this doesn't do the job. Because as you can see, I get more ones instead of zeros in the result.
Is there any more optimal or at least creative way? Or any module to do it?

Update:
It seems the result of this code will never change whether I change the value of `shift` or not .

Comment: Why would you think that getting more ones than zeros is an issue? Random means that you don't necessarily have patterns. When flipping a coin, it will eventually average out to roughly 50% heads, but if you flip the coin 10 times, it is equally likely to come up 10 heads or 10 tails, or 7 heads and 3 tails, or 4 heads and 6 tails. In your example, having 11 ones isn't an indication of a problem or issue - it's not unusual at all. That's not to say your methodology is correct - just pointing out that the results aren't that surprising.

Comment: @KenWhite, yes, you're right. I got your point!

Comment: If you want to force an outcome (e.g. *exactly* 10% of the matrix entries are `1` and the rest are `0`), you could start from a `zeros` matrix, sample a fixed number of indexes from the matrix, and set the values at those indexes to be `1`.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes, that way is also excellent!

Comment: `using SparseArrays; sprand(Bool, 3, 5, 0.2)` is also an option (with several benefits in terms of memory and operation due to sparseness).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`using SparseArrays`?

```
julia> sprand(Bool, 1_000_000,1_000_000, 1e-9)
1000000×1000000 SparseMatrixCSC{Bool, Int64} with 969 stored entries:
⠀⠀⠁⠀⠢⠀⠂⠆⡄⠀⠀⠀⡈⠀⠐⠀⠁⠐⠂⠀⠀⢀⠤⠀⠀⠀⠄⠐⢀⠘⠈⠀⢂⠐⠀⠀⠆⠀⠠⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠈⠁⠀⠑⠀⢀⠐⠀
⠄⠀⡀⠀⠒⠠⠨⢀⣀⠀⠀⠀⠐⠤⠈⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠁⠁⠄⠐⠑⠅⢄⠠⠐⠀⠀⠀⠁⢀⠋⠂⠂⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠄⠀⠀⠀⠄⠈⠀
⠠⠄⠀⢀⠀⢁⠐⠀⠁⠂⢂⠂⠀⠀⠠⠀⠀⠀⠁⠀⠈⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⢀⠂⠀⠈⠀⠀⠀⠠⠀⠂⠄⠀⠄⠀⢀⠀⠀⠉⠀⠠⠤⠀⠒⡐⠀⠂
⢀⠂⠁⠀⠐⠀⠀⠀⠄⠀⢀⡘⠁⠂⠁⠀⠂⢀⠂⠅⡀⠀⠈⠡⠈⠉⢀⠩⠉⠄⡀⠀⠀⠐⠀⡀⡄⠈⠀⢀⠀⠂⠌⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀
⠂⠠⠀⡀⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠂⠐⠀⠀⠂⡁⠁⠉⠈⠀⠀⠁⠀⠄⢀⠤⠀⠀⠁⡂⠠⠀⠄⠀⠀⡀⠀⢀⠥⠀⢉⠀⠀⠄⠁⠀
⠈⠀⠀⠀⠀⠅⠀⠀⠈⠀⠄⡄⠀⠀⠀⠠⠄⠈⠠⠀⠀⠐⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠆⠠⠀⠀⠀⠐⠀⠐⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠌⢠⠀⠀⠂⠐⠈⠀⠀⠐
⠀⡀⠁⠈⡀⠀⢀⠁⠈⠠⡈⠁⢄⠈⠀⠀⠀⢁⠐⣀⠂⠄⠄⢀⠠⠀⠐⠀⠡⠠⠄⠈⢄⢈⠂⠈⠆⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠃⠀⠀⠠⠀⠐⠀⠐⠘⡀
⠀⠂⠁⠰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠄⠀⣐⠀⡄⠤⡀⠀⠄⠀⠐⠀⠉⠁⠀⠈⢀⣐⠠⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⠀⠠⠂⠐⠁⠀⠀⠀⠐⡈⠀⠐⡀⠠⡁⡀⠠⡀⠈
⠈⠀⠀⠠⠀⠀⠀⠁⠠⠐⠀⠐⠄⡀⠠⠀⠀⠀⠐⡀⠀⠀⠄⠀⠀⢒⠈⠊⠀⢢⡠⠀⠀⠀⡈⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠉⠃⠀⡀⡉⠀⢁⠔⠀⠀⠂⠀
⠀⠀⠀⡐⠠⢀⠀⡐⠀⠈⢀⠀⠀⠀⠐⠪⠀⠂⡄⠐⠀⢀⠀⠈⠀⠀⠰⠀⠀⠀⠈⠀⠀⠠⠀⠀⠐⠀⠀⠠⠀⠀⡀⠄⠈⢂⠂⠌⠀⠀⠐⠀
⢀⠜⢈⠀⠤⠂⢄⠀⠘⠀⠀⠀⠈⠀⠀⢀⠄⠀⠠⠀⠠⠀⠀⠀⠁⠐⠁⠀⠀⠈⠁⠀⠀⢀⠀⢄⠀⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⢄⠀⠅⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠠⠦⠀⡐⠈⠐⠀⡄⠀⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⡐⠀⠀⠌⠀⠨⠀⠀⠩⢀⠁⠀⠈⠐⠐⠀⠀⠀⠀⡐⠈⠀⠁⠘⠀⢀⠀⠀⠈⠀⠈⠀⠀⠐⠀⠐⠀⠈
⠀⠀⠀⢄⠤⠀⡀⠀⠀⠬⠀⠀⠂⡡⠀⠌⠠⠠⠀⠀⢀⢔⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠄⠀⡈⠀⠀⠈⠄⡀⠐⠀⠠⠀⠀⠠⠂⠠⠑⠀⠀⡄⢀⠁⠀⠀⢁
⠀⡀⠀⠀⠄⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠄⠀⠂⠀⠁⠀⠀⠁⡠⠀⠀⠡⠀⠂⠂⠄⠀⣀⠄⠊⢀⠁⠀⠄⠀⠀⢀⠀⠄⠀⠁⡀⠈⠁⠀⠀⠀⢂⠀⠈⠂
⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠠⡠⢐⠀⠀⠁⠀⠂⠀⠐⠀⠒⠈⡀⡂⢀⠀⠀⠀⠡⠌⠀⠀⢀⠄⠀⢐⠀⠀⢀⠠⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⠈⠄⠠⡠⠀⡀
⢀⠲⠀⠀⠈⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⠨⠁⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠰⠀⠀⢠⠀⠁⠀⢀⢀⢀⠀⡡⠀⠈⠁⠀⠁⠠⠀⡀⠀⡀⠀⠐⠀⠐⠁⡀⠂⠈
⢀⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠡⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⣂⠀⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠁⠀⢀⠐⠀⠀⠐⠋⠀⠀⠀⢢⠠⠀⠂⠐⠄⢈⠠⠤⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠠⠀⠄⢀⠄⠀⠑⠀⠀⠀⠄⠀⡠⠁⡀⢔⠠⢐⠀⢀⠀⠢⠀⠀⠈⠐⠀⠀⠀⠄⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡄⠀⡈⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠊⡀⠀⢠⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠒⠀⡀⢐⠄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠁⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡄⢀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⢀⢀⠁⠁⠀⠁⠔⠀⠀⠀⠂⠀⠒⠀⢀⢈⢀⠀⠀
⠈⠀⠀⡂⠀⠁⢐⡀⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⡂⠄⠊⠀⠀⠄⢀⠈⠈⠁⠀⠀⠈⠒⠀⠠⠑⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⠄⠆⢄⠀⠀⠂⠂⠀⡀⠀⠀
⠀⠠⠄⠀⠀⠠⡀⠠⠀⠠⠀⠐⠀⠀⡌⠨⢀⠀⠀⠁⠀⠂⠀⡀⠄⠴⠀⢠⠄⠄⠄⡀⠀⠀⠂⢠⠀⠀⠀⠜⠐⠀⠀⠁⢠⠀⠄⠐⠁⠂⠀⠁
⠈⠀⠀⠀⠈⠐⠂⠈⠆⢈⠐⡀⠈⢀⠀⠐⠀⠰⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠠⠀⡂⠨⠀⠈⡀⠁⠀⠤⠈⠐⠂⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠢⠀⠠⠀⠀⠁⠀
⠠⠈⠀⠈⠠⡀⠀⠠⠀⠠⠀⠀⠐⢄⠜⠀⠈⠀⠄⡁⠀⠠⠀⠀⠀⠁⠀⠡⡀⠈⠐⠀⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠐⠐⡈⢀⡠⡂⠀⠀⠐⠀⠄⠀⠀⠀⠁
⢀⠁⠀⢠⠂⢁⠄⡅⠀⠠⠀⠄⠀⠠⠀⠈⡀⠈⠂⠀⠨⠈⢀⠀⢀⡈⠀⠈⡈⠂⠀⠈⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠊⠄⠠⠀⠀⠄⠊⠀⠈⠄⠀
⠂⠀⠀⠀⠌⠁⢀⠀⠐⠀⠀⠈⠀⠀⠁⠀⢀⠁⠪⠠⠀⠀⢐⠀⠀⠄⠀⠂⢀⡀⢐⠁⠀⣀⠒⠀⢀⢀⠀⠠⢂⠀⠀⠠⠀⠄⠐⠄⠁⠀⠀⠀
⠐⠀⠠⠀⠀⡀⠀⠄⠄⠐⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠄⠄⠀⠀⢀⠂⠀⠰⠀⠀⠊⠀⢀⠀⠤⠀⠀⠀⠉⠀⠀⢀⠀⠁⠁⠀⠈⠁⠀⡠⡀⠐⠐⠀⠀⠀
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd choose the [Bernoulli distribution](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/v0.14/univariate.html#Distributions.Bernoulli) for this. Specify a success rate `p`, which takes value `1` with probability `p` and `0` with probability `1-p`.

```
using Distributions

mat = rand(Bernoulli(0.1), 3, 4)
3×4 Matrix{Bool}:
 1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
```

As for your code, you chose `rand()+shift>0.5 ? 0 : 1`, that means if you write `zero_or_one(0.3)` it will give ones with probability `0.2` and zeros with probability `0.8`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you are OK with a `BitMatrix`:

```
julia> onesandzeros(shape...; threshold=0.5) = rand(shape...) .< threshold
onesandzeros (generic function with 1 method)

julia> onesandzeros(5, 8; threshold=0.2)
5×8 BitMatrix:
 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0
 0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 5):

This amounts to sampling from a Binomial distribution.

If 0 and 1 should be equally probable, the default Binomial coefficient `p = 0.5` encodes this:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> rand(Binomial(), 3, 5)
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1  1  1
 1  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  1  1
```

The number of 1s in the matrix is proportional to the parameter `p`, so if the matrix should on average contain ~10% `1` and ~90% `0`, this is the same as sampling from `Binomial(1, 0.1)`:

```
julia> rand(Binomial(1, 0.1), 3, 5)
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1  1
```

See also: [`Distributions.Binomial`](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/v0.14/univariate.html#Distributions.Binomial)

Answer (score 1):

Although based on some comments, I was somewhat convinced that the result of my code was reasonable, each time I investigated its simple procedure, I couldn't withdraw from focusing on it. I found the snag in my code. I forgot that the `let` blocks create a new hard scope area. So if I try returning the `mat` it would show a different and expected result for each run:

```
julia> let mat = Matrix{Int64}(undef, 3, 5)
           zero_or_one(shift) = rand()+shift>0.5 ? 0 : 1
           foreach(x->mat[x]=zero_or_one(0.3), eachindex(mat))
           return mat
       end
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0  1  0
```

Then, for making it available in the global scope, using a `begin` block will make the job get done:

```
julia> begin mat = Matrix{Int64}(undef, 3, 5)
           zero_or_one(shift) = rand()+shift>0.5 ? 0 : 1
           foreach(x->mat[x]=zero_or_one(0.3), eachindex(mat))
       end

julia> mat
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0  1  0
```

(Note that the above results aren't precisely the same.)

Comment: Why are you messing around with `let` blocks and so on, instead of making a `function`?

Comment: @DNF, Just in the case of putting the code here. I mean, there isn't any specific reason. Indeed I don't do it in my projects.